Most likely trajectory of the Gravity Probe A spacecraft, and location of the microwave maser receiver on Earth?
Background/motivation
@PM2Ring's comment under an answer to "Is there a wavelength shift between sunlight observed from the ISS versus from Earth's surface?" in Physics SE links to the alludes to the Pound–Rebka experiment where the measurement of the blue/red shift of photons in a gravity gradient was proposed1. It was confirmed the same year (1960)2 using gamma rays and the incredibly sensitive Mössbauer effect and a modest height difference of about 22.5 meters on Earth.
A further test of the same type, the gravitational blue-shift of a microwave signal sent from space to Earth's surface was performed in 1976 using the satellite Gravity Probe A which was equipped with a 1 part in 1015 frequency stabilized microwave maser. It's signal was received on Earth and compared to an (essentially) identical maser on the ground via heterodyning and measuring the 4 parts in 1010 difference in their frequencies.
Research effort
The linked Wikipedia article mentions that Cospar ID "GRAVR-A" was a Scout sounding rocket launched from Wallops, with an apoapsis of "10,224 km". (There's always that ambiguity if that's really referenced from Earth's center, or it's equatorial radius 6328 km) It links to https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/displayTrajectory.action?id=GRAVR-A with the following information:

NSSDCA ID: GRAVR-A
Launch Information
Launch Date/Time: 1976-06-17T00:00:00Z
Launch Vehicle: Scout
Launch Site: Wallops Island, United States
Decay Date: 1976-06-17
Trajectory Description: No description available.
Trajectory Details
Type: Orbiter
Central Body: Earth
Epoch start (UTC): 1976-06-17 00:00:00
Epoch stop (UTC):  (blank)
Orbital Parameters



Periapsis
Apoapsis
Period
Inclination
Eccentricity




0.10 km
10224.00 km
(blank)
35.000°
0.44471



Regions Traversed: (blank)

Question:
What is the most likely trajectory of the Gravity Probe A spacecraft and where was the experiment's receiver on Earth, based on all information available? For example:

It was launched from Wallops but how far downrange did it return to Earth?
In unambiguous terms, what was its apoapsis and periapsis measured from the center of the Earth? How high did it reach above Earth's surface? These can be estimated - don't worry about a few hundred km, it's that 6378 km ambiguity that's bothering me
Where was the microwave receiver on Earth? Was it at Wallops, or closer to directly under the maximum height where the the shift would have been the most steady?


References:

1Apparent Weight of Photons R. V. Pound and G. A. Rebka, Jr. (1960)
2Measurement of the Gravitational Red Shift Using the Mössbauer Effect in Fe57 T. E. Cranshaw, J. P. Schiffer, and A. B. Whitehead (1960)


My first question in a while; I'll limit it to 1/week max for now and see how things go.

Also related: measuring gravitational time dilation in the Tokyo Skytree with Sr-87 optical lattice atomic clocks. See the excellent article linked in this question for details: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/716323/123208 The uncertainty of the strontium clock is ~1e-17.

Partial answer due to incompletely reproduced reference :(
It was launched from Wallops but how far downrange did it return to Earth?
A map of the groundtrack is shown.

How high did it reach above Earth's surface?
NON-ANSWER
Every other page in the document is missing - it appears that they didn't bother to scan the back sides of the pages sigh - so a lot of info is missing.  Here's a sketch of the trajectory without any numbers. They talk about how precise the trajectory tracking was...

Where was the microwave receiver on Earth? Was it at Wallops, or closer to directly under the maximum height where the the shift would have been the most steady?
There were 3 earth based masers, one at Wallops and two at Merritt Island (MILA) in Florida. The ones at MILA appear to have been the primary ones used in the experiment:

The frequency of signals from the oscillator was monitored on the
ground at Merritt Island, Florida by using two hydrogen masers as
comparison oscillators.

The crucial page 6 is missing, but from reading what remains, it appears all the ground equipment used during the actual flight was at MILA. The second MILA maser was "set up to monitor the primary reference".
Reference: A test of the equivalence principle using a space-borne clock

Excellent answer under challenging/frustrating circumstances, sorry to put you through it :-) In principle, if the Geometry of Accelerations figure was generated with more care than it was photocopied, and if someone was so motivated, a $\Delta t$ could be extracted (duration of (mostly) ballistic flight) which could in principle - with some additional cues from the figure - be used to obtain an approximate apogee. If no further information arises and I can relocate that round tuit I saw somewhere recently, perhaps I'll try. Thanks!

I did see that some of the doppler shift (?) figures had the point of apogee noted on them, and wondered if it could be backed out somehow, but that's way out of my wheelhouse.

I re-googled the title of the report - there's a paywalled version which I might be able to view later today, and then NTRS 19800011717 "Gravitational redshift space-probe experiment" where Table 1 of section 12. Experiment Operations (numbered page 61) seems to have the goods. But what really sticks with me is the checkered hat and plaid pants in Figure 2 of your link.

Yeah, the 70s were a different time. I had some plaid polyester outfits myself, but I could not match the hat. And, looks like you nailed it with that NTRS link. Not sure how I missed that paper.

I hear you - paisley was my pattern de guerre
